# perl + add rule to perl one line command

Tags: perl

The following Perl syntax replaces OLD with NEW, but not if a digit exists before or after the OLD word.

```
 OLD=ABBA1 ; export OLD
 NEW=OBAMA1 ; export NEW

 perl -i -pe 'next if /^ *#/; s/(\b|\D)$ENV{OLD}(\b|\D)/$1$ENV{NEW}$2/g' file
```

#### My question:

I also not want to replace the OLD with NEW if a-z or A-Z letters exist before or after OLD word.

Please advise how to change my Perl syntax in order to do that?

#### Examples (of which OLD word need to replace with NEW):

```
ABBA1R  - not replace
QABBA1  - not replace
ABBA1W  - not replace
@ABBA1  - replace ABBA1 with OBAMA1
ABBA1=  - replace ABBA1 with OBAMA1
ABBA1w  - not replace
4ABBA1  - not replace
ABBA11  - not replace
e  ABBA1  - replace ABBA1 with OBAMA1  (remark between e to ABBA1 I have space)
ABBA1 p   - replace ABBA1 with OBAMA1  (remark between ABBA1 to p I have space)
?ABBA1    - replace ABBA1 with OBAMA1
_ABBA1_   - replace ABBA1 with OBAMA1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
OLD=ABBA1 ; export OLD
NEW=OBAMA1 ; export NEW

perl -pe 'next if /^ *#/;
          s/(\b|[[:^alnum:]])$ENV{OLD}(\b|[[:^alnum:]])/$1$ENV{NEW}$2/g' <<!

ABBA1R  - not replace
QABBA1  - not replace
ABBA1W  - not replace
@ABBA1  - replace
ABBA1=  - replace
ABBA1w  - not replace
4ABBA1  - not replace
ABBA11  - not replace
e  ABBA1  - replace  (remark between e to ABBA1 I have space)
ABBA1 p   - replace   (remark between ABBA1 to p I have space)
?ABBA1    - replace
_ABBA1_   - replace

!
```

It's a shell script - I removed the '`-i`' option since there isn't a file to overwrite (and I want to see the result).

The original script with the `(\b|\D)` constructs were odd; the '`\D`' part (non-digit) allows an alphabetic character to precede the match.  The change to use just '`(\b|[[:^alnum:]])`' twice insists on a word boundary or a non-alphanumeric character.  The word boundary matters at the beginning or end of a line. The captures are now needed.

#### Output

```
ABBA1R  - not replace
QABBA1  - not replace
ABBA1W  - not replace
@OBAMA1  - replace
OBAMA1=  - replace
ABBA1w  - not replace
4ABBA1  - not replace
ABBA11  - not replace
e  OBAMA1  - replace  (remark between e to OBAMA1 I have space)
OBAMA1 p   - replace   (remark between OBAMA1 to p I have space)
?OBAMA1    - replace
_OBAMA1_   - replace
```

Comment: see my queastion if a-z or A-Z before or after OLD word then not need to replace !!!

Comment: You need capture parentheses to use `$1` and `$2`.

Comment: I run perl -pe 'next if /^ *#/; s/$ENV{OLD}/$1$ENV{NEW}$2/g' file and after that ABBA1R was replaced with OBAMA1 why?

Comment: hi "_ABBA1_" must be replaced please can you add this to code

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler sorry my mistake but please add the rule that defined to replace the "_ABBA1_ with "_OBAMA1_"

Comment: see  my update in the queastion (the last line in my queastion)

Comment: just remark OLD should be replace any time if before OLD or after word letters or numbers defined on other cases it should be replace no meter which character appears before or after OLD word

Comment: @jon: revised answer - please remove no longer relevant comments.